# How to include Jars and aars in Android.bp file? Java

Tags: android, android-source, blueprint

In the Aosp module there we can see some prebuilt jars like annotations.jar.
I need to import them in my project using BP file.
Please help me to do that.....
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Use java_import for jar and android_library_import for aar in .bp files.
Example

```
android_app {
  static_libs :[
    "lib1"
    "lib2"
  ],
}
android_library_import {
 name: "lib1"
 aars: ["libs/lib1.aar"],
}
java_import {
  name: "lib2"
  jars: [libs/lib2.jar",
}
```

Comment: How i could use prebuilt jars(eg: support-v4,annotations).

Comment: @jinnings add below in static libs 
 static_libs: [
        "android-support-v4",
 ],
let me know if this works for you

Comment: It worked...But i need to add it as dynamically..